# Nested routes via simple relationship with EmberData and rails API?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I think I have Ember's nested resource down (master-detail). But I'm trying to continue the nest one level deeper but through a `has_many` relationship in my data. I'm using EmberData and Rails as an API, which I believe is setup and working as intended. But nesting one level down in my template and router is stumping me and I can't seem to find examples out there...

This is my current router (using RC1, I think):

```
EmberGallery.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('uploads', function() {
    this.resource('upload', { path: ':upload_id' });
  });
  this.resource('collections', function() {
    this.resource('collection', { path: ':collection_id' });
    this.route('new');
  });
});
```

which produces:

```
/#/uploads/1
/#/collections/1
```

Fine, awesome. But in my app a collection `has_many` uploads, so I'm trying to get to this url (master-detail-detail):

```
/#/collections/1/2
```

id:1 being the `collection_id` (which contains a bunch of uploads, this
    works great)

id:2 being an `upload_id` (how do I get at this?)

What would my router look like? What else would be required for this to work?

EDIT: I'm adding my collection template, which displays and links to the uploads that belong to a singular collection. Basically this displays the associated uploads correctly, but the link takes me back to #/uploads/1 instead of #/collections/1/2 (2 being the upload in collection 1). Obviously my link is wrong, but I suspect my real problem is that I'm pulling in a collection's uploads is improperly.

templates/collection.js.hbs

```
<aside class="span8">
  <header>
  <h4>Collection: {{title}}</h4>
  </header>
  <ul class="thumbnails">
      {{#each upload in uploads}}
        <li class="span3">
          <aside class="thumbnail">
         {{#linkTo 'upload' this}}<img {{bindAttr src="upload.url"}} alt="{{upload.title}}">{{/linkTo}}
          {{title}}
          </aside>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
</aside>
<article class="span4">
  {{outlet}}
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your route `collections.collection` a resource to have this kind of url. To do this:

```
EmberGallery.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('uploads', function() {
        this.resource('upload', { path: ':upload_id' });
    });
    this.resource('collections', function() {
        this.resource(
            'collection',
            { path: ':collection_id' },
            function() {
                this.route('upload', { path: ':upload_id' });
            }
        );
        this.route('new');
    });
});
```

You will have the route `collection.index` (not `collections.collection.index`) implicitly created.
The url `/collections/1/2` will target the route `collection.upload`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. This seems to make sense. Unfortunately I seem to be having other problems with my template naming and perhaps use of my controllers as I can't get this to work... I'm going to add my collection template to my original post.